# Usuário do Windows no IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2008

Estou tentando loga em uma base SQL Server 2008, com o usuário do windows que esta acessando meu site publicado no IIS.

Já configurei o Web.Config para autenticação windows, configurei o pool do aplicativo deixando o `identificador` igual `AplicationPoolIdentity`.

Ao acessar o site eu consigo pegar o usuário correto pelo comando `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. Porém ao tentar conectar no banco de dados esta retornando o seguinte erro `Login failed for user 'dominio\desenvolvedor1$'.` sendo que desenvolvedor1 é nome da minha maquina e não o usuário que esta no windows.

A **String de conexão** está `Data Source=vc9;Initial Catalog=sgt;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name='Controle de Sprint';Pooling=False;`

Se o usuário loga diretamente no banco via Sql Management da certo também, pelo usuário do windows.

Segue como esta configurado as permissões de acesso do IIS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a configuração que você colocou na pergunta parece que faltou configurar o "impersonate=true" no seu web.config.

Coloque o seguinte trecho de código.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

O "impersonate=true" é a ponte para o ISS usar a conta do usuário autenticado no acesso aos recursos externos (SQL, File System, etc...)

Veja maiores detalhes em: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xh507fc5(v=vs.100).aspx

OBS: Verifique se dar acesso ao SQL para os logins dos usuários é ideal na sua solução. Com esse tipo de permissão, um usuário que conheça o endereço do banco de dados pode acessá-lo diretamente (via SQL Management Studio).